# Wordpress Template causes 404 Error

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a page in Wordpress and used this form as template. But when I submit the form it shows `Error 404 page not found`.

I've tried various scripts in php but I didnt get fruitful results. Hoping for the best answers. Thanks :)

Here is my coding

```
<?php
/*
template name: visit
*/

$servername= "localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$database="wp_chandan"; 


if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']))
{

    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    var_dump($email);


    @mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password);
    @mysql_select_db($database);

    $query=mysql_query("insert into visitor_d (NAME,Email) values ('$name','$email') ");    
} ?>

<html>
    <head>  
        <?php get_header(); ?>
        <style type='text/css'>
        /* form elements */
        form {
            margin:100px; 
            padding: 10px 2px;
            background: #F5F5F5;  
            width: 50%;
            height:auto;
            border:1px solid green;
        }

        input {
            padding:2px;
            border:1px solid #eee;
            font: normal 1em Verdana, sans-serif;
            color:#777;
            align:center;
        }

        input.button { 
            font: bold 12px Arial, Sans-serif; 
            height: 24px;
            margin: 0;
            align:center;
            padding: 2px 3px; 
            color: #333;
            background: #e7e6e6 url(MarketPlace-images/button.jpg) repeat-x;
            border: 1px solid #dadada;
        }

        </style>
    </head>

    <form action="" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <legend><b><u>Visitor Details:</u></b></legend>
            Name: <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Fill Name" required><br><br>
            Email: <input type="text" name="email" required placeholder="Enter Email"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit"><br>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <?php get_footer();?>
</html>
```

Comment: `<html>`, `<head>`, `<style>` should be in your header.php. I cant also see the template comment `/* Template Name: My Name */` so not sure how you were able to select this template in backend.

Comment: It looks like there is no route for `POST` method to this `url`.

Comment: comment /* Template Name: My Name */


I've used it but not displayed here.

Comment: You should clean your code and post it as it is.

Comment: Sweet, your code is completely open to MySQL injections.

Comment: what is in your header.php and footer.php ?

Comment: it calls the header as well as footer of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html5 doesn't like the empty action attribute, it does cause issues in some browsers. you have not selected a standard so i assume the browser will default to html5

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
```

Setting the action as `#` should work but one thing to watch out for is actions added before your page template is loaded, this can obviously grab the $_POST and redirects would be common so that may also be a reason.

also

```
Name: <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Fill Name" required>
```

WP does not like when you call a field "name" it conflicts with something (i have forgotten the reason by now)

```
 Name: <input type="text" name="aname" placeholder="Fill Name" required>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you don't have any reserved WordPress terms in the `name` attributes in the fields of the form.

WordPress uses many of these reserved terms for it's internal rewriting and as a result if you using `name` attributes such as "name", it breaks the WordPress rewrite rules and causes this 404 Not Found page after submitting the form.

See more here: http://www.lost-in-code.com/platforms/wordpress/wordpress-404-not-found-when-submitting-form/

Comment: I thought I was going crazy when posting a form to a virtual page (using rewrite rules) with a custom template that always returned the 404 header. simply changing 'name' to '_name' fixed the issue. Thank you so much!